# Merged gridview rows are displayed side by side

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to merge cells of gridview such that if text of cell(0) is same then merge rows. The issue is my merged cells appear side by side rather than one below the other

Please find below my html and vb code

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.vb" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnDataBound="GridView1_DataBound">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="This" HeaderText="This" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Is" HeaderText="Is" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="A" HeaderText="A" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Test" HeaderText="Test" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

VB code

```
Public Class WebForm1
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
        dt.Columns.Add("this")
        dt.Columns.Add("is")
        dt.Columns.Add("a")
        dt.Columns.Add("test")


        Dim dr As DataRow = dt.NewRow()
        dr("this") = "data1"
        dr("is") = "data1"
        dr("a") = "data1"
        dr("test") = "data1"
        dt.Rows.Add(dr)

        dr = dt.NewRow()
        dr("this") = "data1"
        dr("is") = "data1"
        dr("a") = "data1"
        dr("test") = "data1"
        dt.Rows.Add(dr)

        dr = dt.NewRow()
        dr("this") = "data1"
        dr("is") = "data1"
        dr("a") = "data1"
        dr("test") = "data1"
        dt.Rows.Add(dr)

        dr = dt.NewRow()
        dr("this") = "data2"
        dr("is") = "data2"
        dr("a") = "data2"
        dr("test") = "data2"
        dt.Rows.Add(dr)


        dr = dt.NewRow()
        dr("this") = "data2"
        dr("is") = "data2"
        dr("a") = "data2"
        dr("test") = "data2"
        dt.Rows.Add(dr)


        dr = dt.NewRow()
        dr("this") = "data3"
        dr("is") = "data3"
        dr("a") = "data3"
        dr("test") = "data3"
        dt.Rows.Add(dr)


        dr = dt.NewRow()
        dr("this") = "data4"
        dr("is") = "data4"
        dr("a") = "data4"
        dr("test") = "data4"
        dt.Rows.Add(dr)


        dr = dt.NewRow()
        dr("this") = "data4"
        dr("is") = "data4"
        dr("a") = "data4"
        dr("test") = "data4"
        dt.Rows.Add(dr)


        dr = dt.NewRow()
        dr("this") = "data4"
        dr("is") = "data4"
        dr("a") = "data4"
        dr("test") = "data4"
        dt.Rows.Add(dr)


        GridView1.DataSource = dt
        GridView1.DataBind()

    End Sub

    Protected Sub GridView1_DataBound() Handles GridView1.DataBound
        For rowIndex As Integer = GridView1.Rows.Count - 2 To 0 Step -1
            Dim row As GridViewRow = GridView1.Rows(rowIndex)
            Dim previousRow As GridViewRow = GridView1.Rows(rowIndex + 1)

            If row.Cells(0).Text = previousRow.Cells(0).Text Then
                For cellIndex As Integer = 0 To row.Cells.Count - 1
                    If previousRow.Cells(cellIndex).RowSpan < 2 Then
                        row.Cells(cellIndex).RowSpan = 2
                    Else
                        row.Cells(cellIndex).RowSpan = previousRow.Cells(cellIndex).RowSpan + 1
                    End If

                    If cellIndex <> 1 AndAlso cellIndex <> 2 Then
                        previousRow.Cells(cellIndex).Controls.Clear()
                        previousRow.Cells(cellIndex).Controls.Clear()
                    End If
                Next
                'previousRow.Visible = False
            End If

        Next
    End Sub


End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

What it sounds like you need to do is actually remove the cell you are spanning over. When you are giving a cell `RowSpan = 2`, the cell you span into is still there - it just gets bumped over.

```
GridViewRow.Cells.RemoveAt(index);
```